# Is it necessary to check NotifyCollectionChangedAction in a CollectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I wonder if it is necessary to check the 
[`NotifyCollectionChangedAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx) enum of the [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx), when subscribing to the [`CollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event. Every example I stumbled upon does it like this:

```
myCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        foreach (SampleClass sampleObject in eventArgs.NewItems)
        {
            addAction(sampleObject);
        }
    }
    else if (eventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach (SampleClass sampleObject in eventArgs.OldItems)
        {
            removeAction(sampleObject);
        }
    }
    // ...
};
```

Is it possible to ignore the [`NotifyCollectionChangedAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedaction.aspx)  and just simplify the code like this:

```
myCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    eventArgs.NewItems?.OfType<SampleClass>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(addAction);

    eventArgs.OldItems?.OfType<SampleClass>()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(removeAction);
};
```

What are the downsides of this idea? Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, because those code samples are not equivalent. There are more action types than just `Add` and `Remove`. For example there is `Replace` action. If I do this:

```
myCollection[0] = new MyObject();
```

`CollectionChanged` will be fired with action type `Replace`, `OldItems` will contain replaced item (old myCollection[0]) and `NewItems` will contain `new MyObject()` item. First code sample will completely ignore this event. Second code sample will handle both items with `addAction` and `removeAction`. If you do:

```
myCollection.Move(0,1);
```

It will fire event with action `Move` where both `OldItems` and `NewItems` will contain moved item. First sample again will ignore it and second will perform `addAction` and `removeAction` on the same item being moved, which might lead to surprising results I guess.

Comment: In my use-case, it is just necessary to process new and old items. Moving does not matter. If you trigger e.g. the `replace` action, i am processing the old an the new item with my simplified code as well.

Comment: @Wolle You say moving does not matter, but you code will first execute addAction and then removeAction for moved element, I doubt that is what you intend to do in this case (you prefer to ignore it if it really does not matter).